# Use "who are" in a sentence that is not a question

Tags: grammar

I know that we use **are** in present continue in questions: 
who + {is/are} + {verb + ing}

Can I use **who are** also in a sentence that is not a question?

> I think you should not talk to guys **who are** not your age, they
>   could not understand you.

If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to "can I use "who are" in a sentence that is not a question?": YES

I think that the entry in the Cambridge Dictionary is very informative and it got a lot of examples of that particular use

> [**who**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/who) pronoun (USED TO REFER)
>
> used as the subject or object of a verb **to show which person you are
>   referring to**, or to add information about a person just mentioned
>
> I think it was your dad **who** phoned. 
> She's one of those people **who** love
>   to be the centre of attention.
>  He called James, **who** was a good friend
>   as well as the family doctor.

But you asked particularly about "who are". Some examples that I've found in a quick search

*Announce an immediate and unconditional amnesty for all those **who are** imprisoned for political reasons.*

*We represent all the citizens of Europe not just those **who are** organised in NGOs.*

Your sentence

> I think you should not play with guys who are not kick the ball like you

is not correct. "are not kick" is not a valid construction.

This one is correct

> I think you should not play with guys **who are** bigger than you

Maybe what you were trying to say is

> I think you should not play with guys who **don't** kick the ball like you

**do** is the auxiliary verb used to negate **kick**

Answer (score 0):

Since being of a particular age is a state, not a process, we use the simple tense, not the continuous.

> She **is** seventeen.

not

> The toddlers **are being** fourteen months. <sup>NO</sup>

We ask with the simple tense as well:

> **Are** you twenty-one?
>   -- Yes, I **am**.

Comment: ok make sense. So to make sure: I think you should not play with guys who dont kick the ball like you. it's not correct?

Comment: You can use the continuous or the simple tense in your *who*-clause.  Whether one or the other is not appropriate depends on the verb in question and on  your intended meaning. You asked about **BE**  in your question and now you're asking about **KICK**. We could say **who don't kick** or **who aren't kicking** but the meaning would be a tad different.